# Simplify exponential equation

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I really need your help to solve this exponential equation.
It looks so simple, but I haven't been able to find a solution so far:

$$ {A_1 + A_2 \over 2} = A_1 \exp\left({-x^2 \over c_1^2}\right) + A_2 \exp\left({-x^2 \over c_2^2}\right)$$

$$ x = \cdots$$

Comment: This is almost certainly an equation that can't be solved analytically for general values of $A_1,A_2,c_1,c_2$.

Comment: Galois theory tells us that we cannot use usual operations (addition, multiplication, etc.) to solve a sum of exponentials. Check out this related post: http://bit.ly/1Qk2Sih

Answer (score 0):

As Lubos Motl said it is doubtful in the extreme that you will be able to solve this equation analytically.

Suppose that the numbers $A_i$ are positive, then continuity implies that there is at least one solution. Simply evaluate the right hand side and the left hand side separately at both $x=0$ and infinity. Moreover, your right hand side is rapidly decaying function. This property alone will allow to rapidly find a bracket $[0,b]$ which is certain to contain a root. You can then apply the bisection algorithm and narrow the bracket as much as you like or until rounding errors become a problem.